# linear endomorphism between $V$ and dual of $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Let $V$ be a finite dimension vector space over field $K$. $V^*=\{l:V\to K\}$.

Prove $\operatorname{End}(V)$ linear isomorphic to $\operatorname{End}(V^*)$.

My attempt:Since for finite dimension vector space $\dim V^*=\dim V$

so they are linearly isomorphic by $\psi:V\to V^*$.

So given element  $T\in \operatorname{End}(V)$ we can find $\hat{T} = \psi T\psi^{-1}$ is easy to check it's a linear endomorphism.

And the map is onto since for any $\hat{T}$ we can construct $T=\psi^{-1}\hat{T}\psi \in \operatorname{End}(V)$. It's injective since $\hat{T} = 0$ implies $T = 0$ is the zero map, so it has trivial kernel.

Finally we need to show $\phi:\operatorname{End}(V) \to \operatorname{End}(V^*)$ is also linear. i.e. $\phi(T+S) = \phi(T)+\phi(S)$ by definition of $\hat{T}$ it holds.

Is my proof correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is correct. However, there is another vector space isomorphism between $\operatorname{End}(V)$ and $\operatorname{End}(V^*)$ that doesn't require an isomorphism $V \rightarrow V^*$. Namely, map $A \in \operatorname{End}(V)$ to $A^* \in \operatorname{End}(V^*)$ by defining $(A^*\phi)(x) = \phi(Ax)$. Here, $ x\in V$ and $\phi \in V^*$.

Comment: If $V$ is infinite dimension, does this still hold?and why it's linear isomorphism

Comment: Are you sure this is a ring isomorphism? I think it is an *antiisomorphism*, in the sense that $(AB)^*=B^*A^*$.

Comment: @yi_li For infinite dimensions, the map $A \mapsto A^*$ provides an injection of $\operatorname{End}(V)$ into $\operatorname{End}(V^*)$. To see that it is linear, look at $((A+B)^*\phi)(x)$ and use linearity of $\phi$.

Comment: @egreg Sure, it is contravariant. I was implicitly talking about vector space isomorphisms. The op never said anything about rings and/or composition of endomorphisms.

Answer (score 1):

You want to map $T\colon V\to V$ to a linear map $V^*\to V^*$ and there is an obvious way to do it, namely to map $T$ to its transpose $T^*$. However, this defines an *antiisomorphism*, because $(T_1T_2)^*=T_2^*T_1^*$.

You get an isomorphism by using that, when $\dim V=n$, you get $V\cong M_n(K)$ (the ring of $n\times n$ matrices) via the choice of a basis. Transitivity of isomorphism finishes up.